# How do I get the index of an element returned by sample()?

Tags: ruby

I'm using `Array.sample` to return a random element from an array.

I want to then get the index of that element to generate a permalink. Is there a built in method to do this?  Or will I need to roll my own?

Comment: I dont know ruby but I can give an advice to you.. You can create your own class which contains an element from array and also an integer variable. and you can return this instance which created from your class

Comment: If you need both the array value and the index just get a random number 0-size and use it.

Comment: Essentially what you are doing is selecting a random index within the bounds of `0 <= x < length(array)`. Why not just select a random number in this range, and then fetch the item at this index?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think there is a pre-baked solution but you can make your own easily enough. You could use [`sample`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Array.html#method-i-sample) on the indices:

```
i = (0 .. a.length).to_a.sample
e = a[i]
```

That gives you both the index, `i`, and the sampled element, `e`. Or, since you're just extracting a sample of size one, use [`rand`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Random.html#method-i-rand) directly and skip all the [`sample`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Array.html#method-i-sample) noise:

```
i = rand(a.length)
e = a[i]
```

Comment: +1 for the second suggestion. It kills both birds cleanly without generating the intermediate range as an array.

Comment: @theTinMan: I left the first one in as it nicely generalizes to a sample of size `n > 1`.

Comment: For others who are following along, the reason we don't want to create the temporary array is it could theoretically consume a lot of RAM for something that will be thrown away immediately. That's not a good use of RAM or CPU time. The second example steps around that cleanly by reversing the operations.

Answer (score 1):

What about using [find_index](http://apidock.com/ruby/Array/find_index)?

If you have:

```
my_array = [:foo,:qux]
```

You could do:

```
my_sample = my_array.sample
```

And then:

```
my_index = my_array.find_index(my_sample)
```